# Prove the convergence of series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\log(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}})$ by Cauchy criterion

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Given $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\log\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\right)$$
and by definition I need to prove that for $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists n_0 \text{ s.t. } \forall n>n_0, \forall p=1,2,...$

\begin{align}
\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^{n+p}\log(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}) \right |<\epsilon\end{align}
I expanded the sum but wasn't able to get final result for right $n_0$ depending on $\epsilon$. Here's how far I came

\begin{align}\sum_{k=n+1}^{n+p}\log\frac{\sqrt{k}+1}{\sqrt{k}}=\log\frac{(\sqrt{n+1}+1)(\sqrt{n+2}+1)...(\sqrt{n+p}+1)}{\sqrt{(n+1)(n+2)...(n+p)}}\end{align}
taking care of $p$ by choosing it $p=n$ we're having (I hope I haven't done a mistake)

\begin{align}\leq\log\frac{(\sqrt{2n}+1)}{\sqrt{2n}}<\epsilon\end{align}

Any ideas how to continue after this?

Comment: Sine $\log(1+x)\approx x$ when $x$ near $0$, this is going to be hard to prove, since it is false. In particular, $\log\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\right)>\frac{1}{k}$ for $k$ large.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your series **is not** convergent. $\log(1+x)$ is a concave function on the interval $[0,1]$, hence:
$$\forall x\in[0,1],\qquad \log(1+x)\geq x\log 2\tag{1} $$
holds. That gives:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\log\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)&\geq& \log 2\cdot\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\\&\geq& 2\log 2\cdot\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}\right)=\color{red}{\log 4\cdot\left(\sqrt{N+1}-1\right)}\tag{2}\end{eqnarray*} $$
that grows unbounded as $N\to +\infty$.

Comment: Thank you so much, because of my lack of knowledge, I have no experience to "smell" the convergence :)

Answer (score 2):

This does not converge.

$$\log\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\right)=\log(1+\sqrt{k})-\log(\sqrt{k}) > \log(\sqrt{k+1}) - \log(\sqrt{k})$$

This is true because $1+\sqrt{k}>\sqrt{1+k}$ for all $k$, which is easily proven, and because $\log$ is strictly increasing.

Then just see that:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\log(\sqrt{k+1}) - \log(\sqrt{k})\right)=\log(\sqrt{n+1})-\log(\sqrt{1})$$
since that series is telescoping.

More generally, then, if $f(x)$ is non-decreasing and unbounded, then you can show that:

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(f(1+\sqrt{k})-f(\sqrt{k})\right)\to\infty $$

Comment: thank you for your answer sir, I came across to inequality $1+\sqrt{k} > \sqrt{1+k}$ you wrote, but couldnt use it in optimal way, helped out :)

Comment: Not sure what you mean "couldn't use it in optimal way." @shcolf

Comment: well, trying to prove that it is convergent, I didn't used it, thinking about it's decreasing my series, so my conclusions wouldn't be true